# Einstein Content Selection - Content Not Displaying As Per Field Mapping

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

After setting up a banner content block, and adding our Consumer profile data extension I have successfully created a content block that shows when viewing the Test - Customer Profile DE. As below:

[image: Email example]

However when testing the field with a live email build and data extension the banner doesn't align with the criteria. The field names are exactly the same, and they have both been set to a maximum of 100 character limits, but I cannot get an image to show outside of using 'Fallback Content'.

Some of our field attributes do contain punctuation, therefore I am wondering if this would affect the content filters?